# Check connection on publish Paho MQTT Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt, paho

Are there any way  to check connection to MQTT Broker on publish?

Looking for all callbacks, I can't check before or after publish the status from connection. It's publish anyway, without network.

Comment: If there is a direct connection problem an exception will be raised. Also please take the design of MQTT into account. The protocol is make for bad and unreliable connections. If you need guaranteed delivery use the QoS feature.

Comment: I will try to use QoS on my tests. Is there another way than use QoS in MQTT?